# Rearranging Dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, dataframe

I got the following Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
test = pd.DataFrame([["Bugatti","Veyron"],
                     ["Bugatti","Chiron"],
                     ["VW","Golf"],
                     ["VW","Passat"],
                     ["VW","Polo"],
                     ["VW","Caddy"],
                     ["Porsche","Taycan"],
                     ["Porsche","911"]],
                    columns=['Brand', 'Model'])
test
```

I Would like to change it so that you have the brands as (Bugatti,VW,Porsche) as column headers and the models in the column below it. This is just an example for an much bigger list of course. Is there a fast way to rearrange the Dataframe? It Should look like that afterwards.

```
Bugatti  VW      Porsche
Veyron   Golf    Taycan
Chiron   Passat  911
         Polo   
         Caddy
```

Comment: provide expected output

Comment: @akshaynevrekar Sorry totally forgot that. Changed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try transpose or pivot. Transpose will give you multiple column for same brand. While pivot will have null values in result.

Transpose:

```
test.T
```

result

```
Brand  Bugatti  Bugatti    VW      VW    VW     VW  Porsche  Porsche
Model   Veyron   Chiron  Golf  Passat  Polo  Caddy   Taycan      911
```

Pivot:
test.pivot(columns='Brand', values='Model')

result

```
Bugatti Porsche      VW
 Veyron     NaN     NaN
 Chiron     NaN     NaN
    NaN     NaN    Golf
    NaN     NaN  Passat
    NaN     NaN    Polo
    NaN     NaN   Caddy
    NaN  Taycan     NaN
    NaN     911     NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, that already looks quite good. Is there now a way to get rid of the nulls?